# Get the numeric part of an Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, yii2

i have an array like this

```
print_r($_POST['Receipt']['name']);die();
```

will show an array

```
Array ( [Donations] => Array ( [name] => Donations ) [500] => Array ( [amount] => 500 ) [Others] => Array ( [name] => Others ) [600] => Array ( [amount] => 600 ) )
```

how can i get the numeric value only? 
I tried something like this

```
foreach (  $_POST['Receipt']['name'] as $id => $prop )
            {

                if(is_numeric($_POST['Receipt']['name'][$id]))
                {
                    $total_cash= $total_cash + $_POST['Receipt']['name'][$id];
                }   

            }print_r($total_cash);die();
```

but i get a value of zero instead of 1100. I want to get the sum of numeric values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: You should consider rethinking your data structure here. Its quite redundant. An Array of the following kind would serve the same purpose without being bloated:

```
Array ( Donations, 500, Others, 600)
```

It appears to me that a structure that would represent the meaning of the data would look like

```
Array ( [Donations]=> 500, [Others]=> 600)
```

Your approach is basically not wrong. But you should initialize the variable $total_cash before you add to it.

With the data structure you have right now I would go like this:

```
<?php
$total_cash = 0;
foreach ($my_array as $item){
    if (isset($item['amount'])){
        $total_cash += $item['amount'];
    }
}
print_r($total_cash);
die();
?>
```

Regards,

Stefan